# I want to add another column to this comparison

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two sheets by building two Dictionaries and I am very happy with it and the speed it has, but I want to add another two column to the comparison does anyone have any idea how I can add that.

The idea is if column A, sheet1 matches with column B, sheet2 but column C sheet1 don't match column D, sheet2 Print "N" on column F of sheet2and if they all match print "Y" on column F of sheet2.

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim RngList As Object
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sht2 As Worksheet

    Set RngList = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With RngList
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each Rng In Sht1.Range("F2", Sht1.Range("F" &  Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Not .exists(Rng.Value) Then .Add Rng.Value, Rng.Row
        Next Rng

        Worksheets("Current_Month").Activate

        For Each Rng In Sht2.Range("F2", Sht2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))  
            If .exists(Rng.Value) Then
                If Rng.Offset(, 1) <> Sht1.Range("B" & RngList(Rng.Value)) Then Rng.Offset(, 5).Cells = "N"                
            Else
                Rng.Offset(, 5).Cells = "Y"
            End If
        Next Rng
    End With

    Set RngList = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out by doing this if anyone needs it, but thank you anyway.

```
  For Each Rng In Sht1.Range("F2", Sht1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))   
        If Not .exists(Rng.Value) Then .Add Rng.Value, Rng.Row
    Next

     For Each Rng In Sht1.Range("E2", Sht1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 
        If Not .exists(Rng.Value) Then .Add Rng.Value, Rng.Row

    Next
```